# Extracting data from a multi-level hash

Tags: perl, hash, zabbix

I am getting the data structure below as a response from a web service call.

```
my $triggers1 = $zabbix->raw('trigger','get', $options1);
print Dumper($triggers1);
```

Output

```
          $VAR1 = {
                   '10305122' => {
                      'hosts' => [
                                   {
                                     'name' => 'pc4b12cf254444',
                                     'maintenance_type' => '0',
                                     'hostid' => '19295'
                                   }
                                 ],
                      'priority' => '1',
                      'status' => '0',
                      'dependencies' => [],
                      'templateid' => '9892568',
                      'comments' => '',
                      'state' => '0',
                      'triggerid' => '10305122',
                      'expression' => '{14127122}=0',
                      'error' => '',
                      'url' => '',
                      'flags' => '0',
                      'value' => '0',


                    }


           324234' => {
                      'hosts' => [
                                   {
                                     'name' => 'pc45657ba34gy0423',
                                     'maintenance_type' => '0',
                                     'hostid' => '19439'
                                   }
                                 ],
                      'priority' => '1',
                      'status' => '0',
                      'dependencies' => [],
                      'templateid' => '9896452',
                      'comments' => '',
                      'state' => '0',

                      'triggerid' => '10324234',
                      'expression' => '{14167689}=0',
                      'error' => '',
                      'url' => '',
                      'flags' => '0',
                      'value' => '0',
                      'value_flags' => '0',
                      'lastchange' => '1420266068',
                      'type' => '0'

    };
```

etc

There are multiple similar records

From this output, I want to print the values of 'name' and 'value'.

How do I print this using Perl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
    my  $triggers1 = {
               '10305122' => {
                  'hosts' => [
                               {
                                 'name' => 'pc4b12cf254444',
                                 'maintenance_type' => '0',
                                 'hostid' => '19295'
                               }
                             ],
                  'priority' => '1',
                  'status' => '0',
                  'dependencies' => [],
                  'templateid' => '9892568',
                  'comments' => '',
                  'state' => '0',
                  'triggerid' => '10305122',
                  'expression' => '{14127122}=0',
                  'error' => '',
                  'url' => '',
                  'flags' => '0',
                  'value' => '0',


                },


       324234 => {
                  'hosts' => [
                               {
                                 'name' => 'pc45657ba34gy0423',
                                 'maintenance_type' => '0',
                                 'hostid' => '19439'
                               }
                             ],
                  'priority' => '1',
                  'status' => '0',
                  'dependencies' => [],
                  'templateid' => '9896452',
                  'comments' => '',
                  'state' => '0',

                  'triggerid' => '10324234',
                  'expression' => '{14167689}=0',
                  'error' => '',
                  'url' => '',
                  'flags' => '0',
                  'value' => '0',
                  'value_flags' => '0',
                  'lastchange' => '1420266068',
                  'type' => '0'

}
};
```

Code disconnected from data for readability:

```
foreach my $k (keys %$triggers1) {
    print "key=$k";
    foreach my $h (@{$triggers1->{$k}{hosts}}) {
        print "\nname=",$h->{name} // 'not defined';
        //                use this ^^ to avoid Use of uninitialized value in print at 
    }
    print "\nvalue=",$triggers1->{$k}{value} // 'not defined',"\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
key=324234
name=pc45657ba34gy0423
value=0
key=10305122
name=pc4b12cf254444
value=0
```

Comment: Cool. It printed key and value. for print statement for name, it gave this error  Use of uninitialized value in print

Comment: @SandeepMadhu: see my edit. Use `print "\nname=",$h->{name} // 'not defined';`

Comment: For this statement, i am getting error 'Odd number of elements in anonymous hash'                                              my $options1={'nodeids' => '0','triggerids' => 324234,'output' => 'extend','selectHosts' => {'name','hostid','maintenance_status','maintenance_type','maintenanceid','description'},'selectItems' => {'itemid','hostid','key_','name','value_type'},'selectDependencies' => 'extend','selectLastEvent' => '1','expandDescription' => '1','preservekeys' => '1'};   any idea?

Comment: Ignore my previous query. i figured it out.. key value pair was not defined correctly.  Thanks a lot for your help. got the correct result